# Image Displaying and Labeling Code Displays Only: <Figure size 1008x1008 with 0 Axes>

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, imshow

I am making an image classifier using TensorFlow based on the tutorial at https://blog.francium.tech/build-your-own-image-classifier-with-tensorflow-and-keras-dc147a15e38e. I have trained my classifier, and I am now working on the code to label the set of testing images. Here is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))

for cnt, data in enumerate(testing_images[10:40]):

    y = fig.add_subplot(6,5, cnt+1)
    img = data[0]
    data = img.reshape(1,64,64,1)
    model_out = model.predict([data])

    if np.argmax(model_out == 1):
        str_label = "Airplane"
    else:
        str_label = "Rocket"

    y.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.title(str_label)
    y.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    y.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Instead of showing each image in the testing_images array, this is the only thing printed: `<Figure size 1008x1008 with 0 Axes>`
Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: Most probably you have less than 40 images in your array, so the loop is never run?!

Comment: Since it’s a prototype, I only have 8 training and 4 testing images. Why would this influence the loop, though?

Comment: You can't index 40 if the array only contains 4 items.

Comment: Oooh. Thank you so much!